# DecimalFormat not working the same on other machine

Tags: java

I've made a java application where i use DecimalFormat to format the output for numbers.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");      
return Double.parseDouble(df.format(costs));
```

It works fine on my computer, but when  this code execuites on another machine,
i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "25,1"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
```

Both machines have the latest java version installed, both are windows 7. One machine is 64-bit, while the other is 32-bit though. What could be the reason for the error to be happening on the other machine only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Locales, in a word. One machine is European format, `#,#` and the other US/UK, `#.#`.

*Edit:*
Use your DecimalFormat object to travel in both directions: `df.parse(...)` parses the String created by `df.format`.

Comment: I added to the program now that it first sets the locale to US, now it's working fine. The locales were indeed different on the machines.

Answer (score 2):

`df.format(25.1)` returns formatted number `String` based on the default or specified locale.

*i.e.* for `Locale.US` it will return `String` `25.1` while in case of `Locale.ITALY` it will return `25,1` as decimal separators are different for both the locales.

Another *problem* is you are *parsing* the formatted `String` to `double`. If you have `double` value (or something else which is valid number), then you don't need to format the number with `DecimalFormat`.

If you have valid number `String` (`25.1`), you can parse it with `DecimalFormatter` in following way,

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ITALY);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) nf;
df.applyPattern("#.##");
try {
    System.out.println(df.parse("25,1"));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
25.1
```